# C++ with openGL exe file not running

Tags: c++, glut, freeglut

I am coding in code blocks and I created a c++ script that uses openGL. Running the code from codeblocks works perfectly but going into the bin file and running the exe directly spits back the error
*The code execution cannot proceed because libfreeglut.dll was not found*
here is the code

```cpp
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
GLfloat controller = 0.01;
GLfloat change = 0.01;
void Change(int);

void displayMe(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2f(-0.6 + controller,-0.6 + controller);
    glVertex2f(0,-1);
    glVertex2f(-1,-1);
    glVertex2f(-1,0);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2f(0.6 - controller,0.6 - controller);
    glVertex2f(0,1);
    glVertex2f(1,1);
    glVertex2f(1,0);
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(700, 700);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("SAMPLE TEST");
    glutDisplayFunc(displayMe);
    glutTimerFunc(0,Change,0);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
void Change(int a) {
    controller = controller + change;
    if(controller > 0.6) {
        change = -0.01;
    }
    if(controller < -0.6) {
        change = 0.01;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(15,Change,0);

}
```

I was expecting the exe to run the code normally so I cud send it to other computers

Comment: Where is `libfreeglut.dll` located? Especially, where is it located in relation to the executable file you try to run? From which location (directory) are you trying to run the program? Do you run from a command-line environment or from the desktop (double-clicking in a file explorer window)?

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: DLLs are loaded by Windows at runtime. How Windows locates a DLL depends on the *environment* (it has nothing at all to do with your code). The reason that it works with CodeBlocks and does not work without is because of the different environments that exist in those two situations. More [details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order), but it's a complex topic, the simple solution is to make sure that the DLL concerned is either in the same folder as your executable or is in the system folder (usually C:\Windows\System32)

Comment: BTW C++ is not a scripting language, and C++ programs are not called scripts.

Comment: As mentioned above by @john there are a few places where Windows searches for DLL's. There's the Windows system directory, which is not a recommended location for non-system DLL's. There's in the `PATH`, which is what some installers add to. There's the current [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), which is probably what makes it work with your IDE. And there's the same directory as the executable file itself, which is probably the most common for any redistributible DLL.

Comment: If you run from a terminal or command-line window, then your working directory either needs to be the same as where the DLL is located, or the DLL and executable files placed in the same directory. If you run from the desktop by double-clicking the executable icon, then I recommend that the DLL should be in the same directory as the executable program file.